# Create a cache dependancy on a folder and its sub-folder

Tags: asp.net, caching, asp.net-2.0, dependencies

In ASP.NET I would like to store an object in the cache which has a dependancy on all the files in specific folder and its sub-folders.  Just adding the object with a dependancy on the root folder doesn't work.  Is there in any reasonable way to do this other than creating a chain of dependancies on all the files?

Comment: Did this solution I gave worked? - you can use IncludeSubdirectories to include or exclude them. You may find issues due to multiple events fired. Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: Don't know haven't had the time to test it out yet.  Yes you said that already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you can roll your own cache dependency and use FileSystemMonitor to monitor the filesystem changes.

Update: Sample code below

```
public class FolderCacheDependency : CacheDependency
{
    public FolderCacheDependency(string dirName)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(dirName);
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Changed);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Changed);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Changed);
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(watcher_Renamed);
    }

    void watcher_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.NotifyDependencyChanged(this, e);
    }

    void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        this.NotifyDependencyChanged(this, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does FileSystemWatcher raise events when a file in that directory is changed?  FileSystemWatcher watch and entire tree or just the top-level?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones - you can use IncludeSubdirectories to include or exclude them. 

You may find issues due to multiple events fired. Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: This works great. But note you need to set EnableRaisingEvents=true or it won't do anything.